# mod_rewrite accept only dashes & alphanumeric, otherwise throw 404

Tags: php, html, regex, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite to transfer the end of the URL to my php script which will act as a microcms. My url will look something like this: 
`mysite.com/articles/some-article-about-css`

That will pass the following to my PHP script index.php:
`index.php?action=read&article=some-article-about-css`

I have questions:

1. I'm unsure how the best way to only accept alphanumeric w/ dashes using mod_rewrite. I found this rule on the internet `((?:[a-z]+)?(?:[0-9]+)?-?)+` and it apparently doesn't allow double dashes which is even better, but its long and confusing. Is there another (shorter, faster) rule I can use?
2. I'd like to verify that this rule is valid for what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm not very good with mod_rewrite:
   `RewriteRule ^/articles/((?:[a-z]+)?(?:[0-9]+)?-?)+ /index.php?action=read&article=$1`
3. What rule can I use so that if the url after /articles/ is not a valid alphanumeric /w dashes url, automatically throw a 404 rather than passing to my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RewriteRule ^/articles/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /index.php?action=read&article=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^/articles/ - [R=404]

For alphanumeric and dashes only

Answer (score 1):

You dont need that complex regex i believe. Try this

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([^a-zA-Z0-9-]*) /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^articles(.*) [R=404]
```